# SQL - Self join / Recursive query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a table like this

```
ID  GroupName             ParentID  IsFinal 
1   Operator Interface         0     0  
2   Ways to Access             1     0  
3   Network Communication      1     0  
4   Ways of Alarm Reporting    1     0  
5   Desktop                    2     1  
6   POT                        2     1  
7   LAN                        3     1  
8   SMS                        4     1
```

I need a result as

```
ID  GroupName                Parent1          Parent2  ...N..     IsFinal   
1   Operator Interface        NA                NA                 0    
2   Ways to Access          Operator Interface  NA                 0
3   Network Communication   Operator Interface  NA                 0    
4   Ways of Alarm Reporting Operator Interface  NA                 0
5   Desktop                  Ways to Access   Operator Interface    1
6   POT                      Ways to Access   Operator Interface    1   
7   LAN                      Network CommunicationOperator Interface 1  
8   SMS                        ....
```

i am performing self join, its not giving desired result.

```
select * from dbo.Table m left outer join dbo.Table n 
on m.ParentID = n.ID
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What does  `...N..` mean?

Comment: How many levels deep can the relationships be?  Your data imply three levels.

Comment: In short you need to PIVOT a recursive hierarchical CTE

Comment: @Blorgbeard .. N level ..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen .. it can be any level deep

Comment: You need a recursive query then...

Comment: The main issue here is : _it can be any level deep_. With a max deep level it's not really hard do to and can be achieved with a a few dozen of SQL code lines. Still, with an unlimited deepness it's possible to achieve it and as I said above you need a recursive CTE. I would suggest you to read [THIS ARTICLE](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/flattening-hierarchies) carefully. ALL you need is well explained there. Good luck